# Multiple dynamic_reconfigure servers in the same node? [Python]

Tags: python, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to have multiple dynamic_reconfigure servers in the same node?

When I try that I get this error message:

```
Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node
```

Moreover, the first configuration server become unusable.

### I though that it should be possible since a set of nodelets can run on the same node with different dynamic configuration servers. Or it is more complex than it seems?

Edit: Check a more updated question about this issue:  https://answers.ros.org/question/289040/multiple-instances-of-a-dynamic_reconfigure-server-in-the-same-client-node/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12158/multiple-dynamic_reconfigure-servers-in-the-same-node?-%5Bpython%5D/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-05-04**:
#q289040 is similar and much more recent than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is exactly an example of what I was talking. Thanks joq. Just notice that two different node have to be created with different subnames.

Thanks. In any case IHMO it is worthnote that multiple does not seem possible in python because the dynamic_reconfigure server implementation. See

```
$ head -70 `rospack find dynamic_reconfigure`/src/dynamic_reconfigure/server.py
```

I propose a patch at the end of this response with some modification on this file to achieve this feature.

I show a example code below about how could be done it with C++.

```
bool configure_server_callback_a(mypkg::myconfig &config, uint32_t level)
{
  return config;
}

bool configure_server_callback_b(mypkg::myconfig &config, uint32_t level)
{
  return config;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_multiple_configure");

  ros::NodeHandle nh_a("~/a");
  ros::NodeHandle nh_b("~/b");

  dynamic_reconfigure::Server cfg_server_a(nh_a);
  dynamic_reconfigure::Server cfg_server_b(nh_b);

  dynamic_reconfigure::Server::CallbackType f_a, f_b;
  f_a = boost::bind(configure_server_callback_a, _1, _2);
  f_b = boost::bind(configure_server_callback_a, _1, _2);

  cfg_server_a.setCallback(f_a);
  cfg_server_b.setCallback(f_b);

  ros::spin();
}
```

To have multiple dynamic_reconfigure servers on the same node I propose the following patch for the dynamic_reconfigure source:

```
--- a/src/dynamic_reconfigure/server.py Sun Jan 15 19:33:19 2012 -0800
+++ b/src/dynamic_reconfigure/server.py Thu Aug 16 14:06:26 2012 +0200
@@ -51,7 +51,7 @@
 from dynamic_reconfigure.encoding import *
 
 class Server(object):
-    def __init__(self, type, callback):
+     def __init__(self, type, callback,namespace_prefix=""):
         self.mutex = threading.Lock()
         self.type = type
         self.config = type.defaults.copy()
@@ -61,17 +61,19 @@
         self.callback = callback
         self._clamp(self.config) 
 
+   self.namespace_prefix=("~/"+namespace_prefix+'/').replace('//','/')
+
         # setup group defaults
         self.config['groups'] = get_tree(self.description)
         self.config = initial_config(encode_config(self.config), type.config_description)
 
-        self.descr_topic = rospy.Publisher('~parameter_descriptions', ConfigDescrMsg, latch=True)
+        self.descr_topic = rospy.Publisher(self.namespace_prefix+'parameter_descriptions', ConfigDescrMsg, latch=True)
         self.descr_topic.publish(self.description);
-        
-        self.update_topic = rospy.Publisher('~parameter_updates', ConfigMsg, latch=True)
+
+        self.update_topic = rospy.Publisher(self.namespace_prefix+'parameter_updates', ConfigMsg, latch=True)
         self._change_config(self.config, type.all_level)
         
-        self.set_service = rospy.Service('~set_parameters', ReconfigureSrv, self._set_callback)
+        self.set_service = rospy.Service(self.namespace_prefix+'set_parameters', ReconfigureSrv, self._set_callback)
 
     def update_configuration(self, changes):
         with self.mutex:
@@ -89,7 +91,7 @@
 
     def _copy_to_parameter_server(self):
         for param in extract_params(self.type.config_description):
-            rospy.set_param('~' + param['name'], self.config[param['name']])
+            rospy.set_param(self.namespace_prefix+ param['name'], self.config[param['name']])
 
     def _change_config(self, config, level):
         self.config = self.callback(config, level)
```

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-16**:
If you have not already, I recommend opening a Track enhancement ticket for your patch.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-08-16**:
Here it is: https://kforge.ros.org/dynamicreconfig/trac/ticket/10
Regards.

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-12-05**:
Hi in the tutorial "http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode" there is no node handle specified in the code, does this means if you don’t give the constructor a handle it will use some default handle?

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2013-12-16**:
That is the point that was being discussed in this question. As far as I tested (in fuerte) it was not possible to create multiple dynamic_reconfigure servers (in python) since you could not specify the url or namespace of the dynamic reconfigure server. Conversely, it is possible to do it in c++.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you can define multiple servers using different `ros::NodeHandle` instances with separate subordinate namespaces.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was doing something very similar. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1059742) (and [this ROS ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3394) for why I didn't submit it). It's obsolete for me now, so I won't push on this. But in comparison to your patch, I also modified the _copy_from_parameter_server() and _change_config() methods.

---

Originally posted by [AndrewStraw](https://answers.ros.org/users/203/andrewstraw/) with karma: 171 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-08-17**:
Yep, thanks Andrew. I solved that and submitted a second version of the patch.